# julia: outer product function

Tags: r, julia

In `R`, the function `outer` structurally allows you to take the outer product of two vectors `x` and `y` while providing a number of options for the actual function applied to each combination. For example `outer(x,y,'-')` creates an "outer product" matrix of the elementwise differences between `x` and `y`. Does Julia have something similar?

Comment: Why not just use `x * y'`? Not sure what the `-` is if it's an outer product. Or you may be looking for broadcast: `x .- y'`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Broadcast is the Julia operation which occurs when adding `.`'s around. When the two containers have the same size, it's an element-wise operation. Example: `x.*y` is element-wise if `size(x)==size(y)`. However, when the shapes don't match, then broadcast really comes into effect. If one of them is a row vector and one of them is a column vector, then the output will be 2D with `out[i,j]` matching the `i`th row of the column vector with the `j` row vector. This means `x .* y` is a peculiar way to write the outer product if one a row and the other is a column vector.

In general, what broadcast is doing is:

> This is wasteful when dimensions get large, so Julia offers broadcast(), which expands singleton dimensions in array arguments to match the corresponding dimension in the other array without using extra memory

(This is from [the Julia Manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/arrays/#broadcasting))

But this generalizes to all of the other binary operators, so `x .- y'` is what you're looking for.

Comment: In fact, `x .- y'` is what (s)he is looking for.

Comment: Great, thank you! Is there a way to generalize beyond (`+`,`-`,`*`,`/`)? For example, is there a preferred way to do this with some function `f` that takes two arguments?

Comment: Any binary operator can be broadcasted like this. For function calls, you can do `f.(x,y')`.

Comment: What if you don't know a priori whether `size(x)==size(y)` or not. But you definitely want the outer product matrix in either case.

Comment: That doesn't matter for outer products and I explained why.

Comment: A row and a column vector only have the same size when one of them has length 1. Got it.