# Filling in Julia matrix with nested for loops

Tags: for-loop, matrix, julia

I have two arrays and an empty matrix, I need to perform a function such that the resulting matrix includes every combination of the two arrays.

Unfortunately I cannot run the arrays separately as they are both optional parameters for the function. I thought that the best way to do this was through nested loops but now I am unsure...

I've tried multiplying one of the matrices so that it includes the necessary duplicates, but I struggled with that as the real data is somewhat larger.

I've tried many versions of these nested loops.

```
a = [ 1 2 3 ]
b = [ 4 5 6 7 ]
ab = zeros(3,4)

for i = 1:length(a)
    for j = 1:length(b)
        ab[??] = function(x = a[??], y = b[??])
    end
end
```

ab = [1x4 1x5 1x6 1x7, 2x4 2x5 2x6 2x7, 3x4 3x5 3x6 3x7]

Answer (score 3):

Your problem can be solved by [broadcasting](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.6.1/manual/arrays/#Broadcasting-1):

```
julia> f(x, y) = (x,y)   # trivial example
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f.([1 2 3]', [4 5 6 7])
3×4 Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},2}:
 (1, 4)  (1, 5)  (1, 6)  (1, 7)
 (2, 4)  (2, 5)  (2, 6)  (2, 7)
 (3, 4)  (3, 5)  (3, 6)  (3, 7)
```

The prime in `a'` transposes `a` to make the shapes work out correctly.

But note that `a = [ 1 2 3 ]` constructs a `1×3 Array{Int64,2}`, which is a matrix.  For a vector (what you probably call "array"), use commas: `a = [ 1, 2, 3 ]` etc.  If you have your data in that form, you have to transpose the other way round:

```
julia> f.([1,2,3], [4,5,6,7]')
3×4 Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},2}:
 (1, 4)  (1, 5)  (1, 6)  (1, 7)
 (2, 4)  (2, 5)  (2, 6)  (2, 7)
 (3, 4)  (3, 5)  (3, 6)  (3, 7)
```

BTW, this is called an ["outer product"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44591481/1346276) (for `f = *`), or a generalization of it.  And if `f` is an operator `∘`, you can use dotted infix broadcasting: `a' ∘. b`.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't that just

```
a'.*b
```

?

Oh, now I have to write some more characters to get past the minimum acceptable answer length but I don't really have anything to add, I hope the code is self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

Also a list comprehension:

```
julia> a = [1,2,3];

julia> b = [4,5,6,7];

julia> ab = [(x,y) for x in a, y in b]
3×4 Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},2}:
 (1, 4)  (1, 5)  (1, 6)  (1, 7)
 (2, 4)  (2, 5)  (2, 6)  (2, 7)
 (3, 4)  (3, 5)  (3, 6)  (3, 7)
```